# @HostListener for KeyCommands not working [Electron, Angular]

Tags: angular, electron

I am quite new to Electron and Angular and trying to write a small app. In my application, I want to catch some general Key Commands. To catch the events I wrote a directive, but the application will not react to any user-input whatever I do. Might this be a problem with usage of angular and electron or do I make a simple mistake in the usage of angular?

- directive gets declared in app-module
- directive is attached to the specific component(simple one-pager)

```
    import {Directive, HostListener} from '@angular/core';


    @Directive({
      selector: '[appUserinputControl]'
    })

    export class UserinputControlDirective {

      @HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeyDown(res) {
        console.log('Key', res);
      }

      constructor() {
      }

    }
```

The code should log keydown-events to the console, but it does nothing and no error appears.

Answer (score 0):

I think the bit that you are missing is that you have used document.keydown instead of window.keydown.

```
    @HostListener('window:keydown', ['$event'])
    keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
   console.log(event)
}
```

Example above should work.